# AS3 - Using graphics.clear not working as expected

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Would anyone know why using graphics.clear(); in this example is preventing the graphics from being drawn?

e.g. the following code works and the lines are drawn.

```
var my_shape:Shape = new Shape();
my_shape.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x00FF00, 1);
addChild(my_shape);

function moveLines():void { 
my_shape.graphics.moveTo(10, 10); 
my_shape.graphics.lineTo(50, 50);
my_shape.graphics.lineTo(100, 100);
}

moveLines();
```

But if I add the clear() command nothing is drawn.

```
function moveLines():void { 
my_shape.graphics.clear();  
my_shape.graphics.moveTo(10, 10); 
my_shape.graphics.lineTo(50, 50);
my_shape.graphics.lineTo(100, 100);
}

moveLines();
```

I'm wanting to animate the line moving so would like to clear the previous drawing before redrawing the lines.

Thanks

Comment: Long time since I've touched this, but it seems to me you have to re-set the linestyle too.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks. If you want to post that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to re-set the linestyle too, so move

```
my_shape.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x00FF00, 1);
```

to your `moveLines()` method, after the 'clear' of cource.